# Eclipse Breakpoint Variables Window

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

Is there a way in Eclipse to make it default to the variables tab rather than the debug (stacktrace) tab? For example, currently if I set a break point in a for-loop, when it breaks it shows the debug tab. If I go to the variables tab then press resume, next time it breaks it goes back to the debug tab. Is there a way I can make it stay on the current tab or atleast default to the variables tab?

Comment: I do not see this behavior using Eclipse Juno 4.2.1.  What version are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest Spring Tools Suite which is basically the latest version of eclipse. This happens when you have a variable and debug tab on the same window. For now, I am working around this by simply moving the variables tab to a different window.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer I could find is to hide the screen (essentially pulling it to the far right). I do not think Eclipse has a solution for this.